# Hosting my own Cloud IDE like cloud9

Tags: server, php, ide

Hi I have a headless ubuntu server and would like to install some sort of cloud9 like IDE - any suggestions with instructions?

Code highlighting and hinting would be excellent. This is for mainly PHP development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend [Codiad](http://codiad.com/) - dark theme, git, terminal, easy setup without big dependencies.

[image]

Comment: I ended up installing this and using it. Quite easy to get up and running.

Answer (score 6):

For the benefit of others stumbling onto this question and the answers, this is a fast moving target, because development in all dependent technologies is rapidly changing.

I don't think there is any need to go through the manual process of building rvm/npm anymore.  Most distros now ship with decent versions of those tools and even nodejs itself.

So, best to do a quick review of the requirements at their [github site](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) .. and follow their lead in deploying cloud9.

For me, the steps that have worked (ubuntu 12.04, xfce) are as follows:

- I already had nodejs (0.10.26) and npm (1.4.3) installed
- so, `npm install -g sm` ..
- then `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` ..
- `useradd -m cloud9`
- `su - cloud9`
- `git clone git://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git`
- `cd cloud9`
- `npm install`

All the above completed successfully without errors.  The npm install does take a while because it builds all required dependencies.

The following is taken verbatim from the cloud9 website, and it works as stated:

---

#### Running

- `bin/cloud9.sh`  .. runs on default tcp 3131, accessible from `http://localhost:3131`
- `bin/cloud9.sh -w ~/myproject` .. runs with a specified project
- `bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0`  .. listen on all interfaces
- `bin/cloud9.sh --username user --password somepassword` .. run with basic auth, requiring the username/password to access it

Comment: It's even easier to deploy a cloud9 clone on your own machine using docker. Just install docker by doing `curl https://get.docker.com | sudo bash` and then start a cloud9 container using `docker run -it -d -p 80:80 -v /your-path/workspace/:/workspace/ kdelfour/cloud9-docker`. Don't forget that in that container you're root, so file permissions on the host need to be fixed when you want to use the app outside the development container. Or you could just share that volume with another docker container that runs your app.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed cloud9 IDE yesterday (and tried the whole last week) on ubuntu server 12.04, it's kind of tricky, but I figured out how to do it (with the help of http://www.samclarke.com/2012/07/how-to-install-cloud-9-ide-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/).

If you have nodejs installed, you first have to uninstall it and you need to install some extra packages:
`sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils git libxml2-dev`

You should create a new user called "cloud9" for example `sudo adduser cloud9`. Everything that follows has to be done as the new user!

Install the node version manager (nvm) in the home directory of cloud9 by using:

- `git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/nvm`
- `echo '. ~/nvm/nvm.sh' >> ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc`

Now install nodejs 0.8.23 using nvm:

- `nvm install v0.8.23`
- `nvm use v0.8.23`

Install sourcemint via npm:

- `npm install sm`

Clone the cloud9 git repository into the home directory of cloud9:

- `git clone git://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git`

Change into the directory "cloud9" and run sourcemint:

- `../node_modules/sm/bin/sm install`

Now you can start cloud9 with ~/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh.

To automatically start cloud9 you need a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# It is important to use bash here and not sh!
. ~/nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use v0.8.23
~/cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh
```

The script has to have executable permissions!

You can start the server at startup by adding the following line to /etc/rc.local:
`su cloud9 -c /home/cloud9/scriptname.sh &`

If you want cloud9 to be accessible on port 80 add the following to your virtualhost entry in apache2:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3131
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3131
```

(maybe / and http://... need to be the other way round, I'm not sure)

Then enable the mod_proxy module of apache2: `sudo a2enmod mod_proxy`

And restart apache2: `sudo service apache2 restart`

That's it, now you have a working installation of cloud9 on ubuntu server!

Comment: I have since switched to my original love; Debian. But I will try then when I get home. Hope it works :)

Comment: @OmarMir I made a mistake in the script. The point in the 3rd line was missing.

Comment: As time passes, the compatibility with different versions of nodejs is changing, so the only way to make it work is trying node-versions until sourcemint (sm) installs properly and everything else is working.

Answer (score -2):

Also you can use [koding.com](http://koding.com) without installing full ide on your server - you will need to install only plugin that needed to connect to your machine over ssh. So, here you will have terminal and file viewer - working nice for me.
[image: ide in browser]

Another cloud IDE without installing anything at your server, even plugin for connection - [codeanywhere.com](http://codeanywhere.com):
[image: codeanywhere, online ide]

And [Eclipse Che](https://eclipse.org/che/) that now in Alpha and I not tested it but looking good:
[image: ide in browser, online text editor]

Also you can use `vi` as nice text editor - you will need only to connect over `ssh` to your machine.

And another option - you can use [atom](http://atom.io) with some plugin for remote editing of files, or you can edit file locally and click some buttons to upload file to server (with `git` of with some plugin).

Comment: Koding is no longer free :(